# Change data connection sql query in LiveCycle based on external data

Tags: xml, pdf, data-binding, livecycle, livecycle-designer

I have a PDF form in LiveCycle Designer ES4 which has a data connection to an Access database.
I would like to AUTOMATICALLY populate the form with data from the database, based on information in an XML file.

For example, I have the following file, `name.xml`:

```
<Form>
    <Name>Mike</Name>
</Form>
```

I would like all the form fields to populate as if the following query had run:

```
SELECT * FROM Info WHERE Name = 'Mike'
```

I have thought about a few methods of doing this that make sense to me.  Either

1. Import the data from the file and create a query string, something like

   ```
   var nameXML = xfa.loadXML("name.xml")
   var name = nameXML."parseTheXMLSomehow"
   $.DataConnection.#command.query.commandType = "text" 
   $.DataConnection.#command.query.select.nodes.item(0).value =
       Concat("SELECT * FROM Info WHERE Name = '", name, "'") 
   $.DataConnection.open()
   ```
2. Create a data connection to the XML file and bind it to the `Name` field, and then somehow change all the other fields as in the option above, or
3. Retrieve the data as in the first option, then set the value of the `Name` field (which is bound to the data connection to the database) to the data value, and somehow have that automatically change everything else.

Problems:

1. `loadXML` doesn't work with data files, and `xfa.host.importData("name.xml")` doesn't seem to do anything (maybe because the document isn't certified  - couldn't understand how to do that)
2. I can create the data connection to the XML file and bind it to a field, but it doesn't display anything.  Is there something I need to add to the XML file?
3. I can't get the data in the first place, and even if I could, changing one field doesn't automatically change the others, even though they're all bound to the same data source.

Right now, the second option seems to be my best bet if I could get the data to actually populate.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Before moving forward, make sure you understand the concept of Reader Extensions.

Your PDF must be applied with appropriate Usage Rights (more specifically 'Database and Web service Connectivity') before loading data into it.

You did not create a data connection directly to your XML file. Rather you would have created a data source from a sample XML file. This will just use the schema of the XML - not the actual data.

If you want to change the values of all fields at the same, set Global Data Binding.

Hope these tips may help you.
-Nith